# Show main content next to side menu

Tags: html, css

I want to have a side menu with content on the remaining width of the page.

What my issue is, is that the main content doesn't seem too be seeing the nav menu and is going underneath the menu.

**What I expect to happen**

```
| NAV  |  MAIN CONTENT  |
```

**What's happening**

```
| MAIN CONTENT & NAV  | MAIN CONTENT |
```

**Code**

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 13%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("/imgs/header-home-bg.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <p>Analytix</p>
      <div class="seperator"></div>
      <li class="dashboard"><a href=""><span class="entypo-chart-pie"></span>Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li class="myreports"><a href=""><span class="entypo-doc-text"></span>Tab 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="datapub"><a href=""><span class="entypo-print"></span>Tab 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="admin"><a href=""><span class="entypo-user"></span>Administration</a>
      </li>
      <li class="settings"><a href=""><span class="entypo-cog"></span>Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li class="logout-submit"><a href=""><span class="entypo-logout"></span>Log out</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<section>
  <h3>MAIN CONTENT</h3>
</section>
```

Comment: It's because of this: position: fixed; :).
So your containers are not related to eachother and i this case content will always go under the nav. 
So, change position to relative/static or move content to the right and change his width.

Comment: What's the purpose of the wrapper element?

Answer (score 2):

You won't need `float` or `flex` in this situation.

Simply give the main content a left-margin as wide as (or slightly wider than) the width of the `position:fixed` `nav`.

So, if the `nav` has a width declaration of `width: 13%;`

You can declare:

```
section {
margin-left: 13.5%;
}
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to margin over padding?

Comment: Yes - the `padding` of an element is _inside_ the element. The `margin` is outside the element. If you use padding instead of margin and (later on) give the element a `border` or a `box-shadow` the latter will be on the far side of the `padding`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need `float` in this case ,

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from
>   the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its
>   container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

**SyntaxEDIT**

```
float: left;
float: right;
float: none;
float: inline-start;
float: inline-end;

/* Global values */
float: inherit;
float: initial;
float: unset;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float

```css
nav {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:13%;
    height:100%;
    background-image: url("/imgs/header-home-bg.jpg");
    float:left;
    margin-right:40px;
    
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <p>Analytix</p>
            <div class="seperator"></div>
            <li class="dashboard"><a href=""><span class="entypo-chart-pie"></span>Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="myreports"><a href=""><span class="entypo-doc-text"></span>Tab 2</a></li>
            <li class="datapub"><a href=""><span class="entypo-print"></span>Tab 3</a></li>
            <li class="admin"><a href=""><span class="entypo-user"></span>Administration</a></li>
            <li class="settings"><a href=""><span class="entypo-cog"></span>Settings</a></li>
            <li class="logout-submit"><a href=""><span class="entypo-logout"></span>Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<section>
    <h3>MAIN CONTENT</h3>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case give your `<section>` the remaining width(**100% - width of the sidebar**) & float it to the right. Simple

```
section {
  width: 87%;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-left` on the body as much as you've given to `<nav>`, in my case `margin-left: calc(35% + 20px);`

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x200");
  word-break: break-all;
}

body {
  margin-left: calc(35% + 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <p>Analytix</p>
      <div class="seperator"></div>
      <li class="dashboard"><a href=""><span class="entypo-chart-pie"></span>Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li class="myreports"><a href=""><span class="entypo-doc-text"></span>Tab 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="datapub"><a href=""><span class="entypo-print"></span>Tab 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="admin"><a href=""><span class="entypo-user"></span>Administration</a>
      </li>
      <li class="settings"><a href=""><span class="entypo-cog"></span>Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li class="logout-submit"><a href=""><span class="entypo-logout"></span>Log out</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<section>
  <h3>MAIN CONTENT</h3>
</section>
```

Hope this helps!